# Array of constants in php

Tags: php, html

I am a starter in web development. My requirement in a bit unique here. I have a set of scores, score_1 to score_n. Each score is associated with a factor with which it affects the grand score. Now I wish to write a `configuration.php` file as:

```
<?php
define("NUMBER_SCORES",4,true);
define("FACT_SCORE[1]",0.2,TRUE);
define("FACT_SCORE[2]",0.6,TRUE);
define("FACT_SCORE[3]",0.8,TRUE);
define("FACT_SCORE[4]",0.6,TRUE);
define("FACT_SCORE[5]",0.7,TRUE);
?>
```

and then I wish to iterate over these values like this:

```
<?php
function grand_total()
{
                                $agg_score=0;
                for($i=1;$i<=number_scores+1;$i++)
                $agg_score=$agg_score+ (FACT_SCORE[$i])*$scores[$i];
                return $agg_score;
}
?>
```

Well I know that this is not the right way to do it, but I can't figure out how I attain this functionality? The `configuration.php` file is often changed to meet the desired requirements while many other pages use the data in it. Is there any other way of achieving this?

Comment: assume $scores[$i] etc.. have correct values. I skipped quite a bit of code that calculates this.

Comment: Can't you define a static array?

Comment: I don't want an array.... array is changeable throughout the application, i don't want that. I need it to be constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have constants with fancy names, you need to use [constant()](http://php.net/constant) to call them:

```
constant('FACT_SCORE[' . $i . ']')
```

Of course, given that it isn't an array, it may be less confusing to get rid of square brackets:

```
define("FACT_SCORE_1",0.2,TRUE);
define("FACT_SCORE_2",0.6,TRUE);
define("FACT_SCORE_3",0.8,TRUE);
define("FACT_SCORE_4",0.6,TRUE);
define("FACT_SCORE_5",0.7,TRUE);
```

Or simply use an array ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make it in an array? The syntax is even cleaner:

```
$FACT_SCORE = array(
    1 => 0.2,
    2 => 0.6,
    3 => 0.8,
    4 => 0.6,
    5 => 0.7
);
```

And then simply:

```
function grand_total()
{
    $agg_score=0;
    foreach ( $FACT_SCORE as $i => $k )
        $agg_score += $scores[$i]*$k;
    return $agg_score;
}
```

Comment: There is chance for modifying the values of this array with in another file (which includes this) right??

Comment: @sasidhar - Well, yes, arrays aren't read-only. If you want to protect against this, you could write a class that wraps this array into a read-only `Iterator`/`ArrayAccess`. Or maybe simply a function that returns this array, so you'd always be using a copy of it.

Comment: i guess Álvaro G. Vicario's answer does the trick in a simple manner

Comment: @sasidhar - Well, I kinda think that the array approach is even simpler. Just to note - I haven't had the problem that a configuration setting would be accidentally changed at runtime, even though it was modifiable. And, if you say that it changes often, then I would expect that the user might soon desire a better UI for modifying these constants, and an array would be a lot easier then. But - have it your way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$fact_score = array(null, 0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.6, 0.7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would defining a static array work for you?

```
static $FACT_SCORE = array(
    0.2, 0.6, 0.8,
    0.6, 0.7
);

function grand_total()
{
    $agg_score = 0;

    for($i = 1; $i <= number_scores + 1; $i++)
        $agg_score += $FACT_SCORE[$i - 1] * $scores[$i];

    return $agg_score;
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `static` wont prevent you from modifying the variable.

Answer (score 0):

> Well i know that this is not the right way to do it, but i cant figure out how i attain this functionality.

I wouldn't use constants for this, to be totally honest. A simple array would suffice, although that would be changeable throughout the application. If you're still inclined to use constants to accomplish your goal, you can use something like this:

```
define("NUMBER_SCORES",5,true);
define("FACT_SCORE[1]",0.2,TRUE);
define("FACT_SCORE[2]",0.6,TRUE);
define("FACT_SCORE[3]",0.8,TRUE);
define("FACT_SCORE[4]",0.6,TRUE);
define("FACT_SCORE[5]",0.7,TRUE);

function grand_total()
{
    /** Making this up, as it's not in the example. */
    $scores = array( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );

    $agg_score=0;
    for($i=1; $i <= NUMBER_SCORES; $i++ ) {
        $agg_score += constant( 'FACT_SCORE[' . $i . ']' ) * $scores[$i];
    }
    return $agg_score;
}


var_dump( grand_total( ) );
```

EDIT: changed and tested the example, seems to work for me. Last example had a spelling error, and $scores wasn't defined.

Comment: @sasidhar Try the changed example, it seems to work for me. The outcome of the script above is float(9.7). Mind you though; I agree with the rest of the posters: an array (either static or plain) should suffice.

Comment: @Berry Langerak yeah the use of constant() does the trick. I preferred the use of constants as i wanted them to be read-only. But i agree there are other ways. But i see this is simple.

Comment: @sasidhar - mind you, [constants can be redefined too](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-constant-redefine.php), if one really wants to...

Comment: @Vilx +1 but thats no accident i guess. We are a group of people working together. So i don't want any of them to accidentally update these values.

Comment: @sasidhar - as I said, hasn't happened to me. Hence my opinion is that this is an overkill. But, again - do as you like. This approach works as well.

Comment: @sasidhar - Peace. :) Never meant it otherwise. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign arrays to constants. What you could do, would be:

```
<?php
define("FACT_SCORE", serialize(array(0.2, 0.4)), TRUE);

foreach (unserialize(FACT_SCORE) as $value) {
    echo $value; // or calc some stuff
}
```

Although this is not far from beautiful...